# split button menu item click action

Tags: extjs4.1, split-button

I have a split button that have items and I want when I click on item I do something

I work with extjs 4 I'm working with action on simple button and it work but with split button it doesn't work

this is my view code of split button

```
{
                 xtype:'splitbutton',
             //   x:300,
                text: 'Parametre',
                iconCls: 'add16',
                cls:'badd',

                menu: [{text: 'D�connexion',iconCls: 'logout',action:'logout'},{ text: 'R�glage de la Langue',iconCls: 'lang',
```

and this is my controller function of action

```
'westmenu button[action=meet]': {  

                'itemclick' :this.meet
            },

logout:function(button) 
    {
           //this.getHome().close();

                var form = button.up('westmenu');
               form.getForm().submit({
                   url:'j_spring_security_logout',
               });   

            }
```

any one have a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recuperate the click on the split button try with:

```
'westmenu splitbutton[action=meet]': {  
    click :this.meet
},
```

else if you want to recuperate the click on the item try with:

```
'westmenu menuitem[action=meet]': {  
     click :this.meet
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 xtype:'splitbutton',
 //   x:300,
 text: 'Parametre',
 iconCls: 'add16',
 cls:'badd',
 action:'meet',//<-you should add action property into button
```